# Invalid base64 encoding of non-ASCII characters in common lisp

Tags: unicode, base64, lisp, common-lisp

I'm porting some encryption software to common lisp.  It's an exercise I've done in a number of other languages.  It requires base64 encoding of UTF-8 strings, including non-ASCII characters.  My first unit test checks this with the string "abcd£".  The expected value in base64 is "YWJjZMKj".  (I checked this at https://www.base64encode.org/ too).  I've tried two lisp packages, cl-base64 and base64 and each returns "YWJjZKM=".

I'm running sbcl 2.3.2 on windows 10. :SB-UNICODE is in the *FEATURES* list.  I've tried both strings and the usb8 array offered by cl-base64.  Here's my fiveam tests:

```lisp
(in-package :rsearch-tests)

(def-suite test-encryption
    :description "test encryption functions")

(in-suite test-encryption)

(test feature
      (is-true (member :sb-unicode *features*) t))
(test base64-1
      (is (string= "YWJjZMKj" (cl-base64:string-to-base64-string "abcd£"))))
(test base64-3
      (is (string= "YWJjZMKj" (cl-base64:usb8-array-to-base64-string
                               (stdutils:string-to-usb8-array "abcd£")))))
```

That's a pound sterling symbol at the end of the test string.

Here's the test output:

```
Running test suite TEST-ENCRYPTION
 Running test FEATURE .
 Running test BASE64-1 f
 Running test BASE64-2 f
 Did 3 checks.
    Pass: 1 (33%)
    Skip: 0 ( 0%)
    Fail: 2 (66%)

 Failure Details:
 --------------------------------
 BASE64-2 in TEST-ENCRYPTION []:

(CL-BASE64:USB8-ARRAY-TO-BASE64-STRING (STDUTILS:STRING-TO-USB8-ARRAY "abcd£"))

 evaluated to

"YWJjZKM="

 which is not

STRING=

 to

"YWJjZMKj"


 --------------------------------
 --------------------------------
 BASE64-1 in TEST-ENCRYPTION []:

(CL-BASE64:STRING-TO-BASE64-STRING "abcd£")

 evaluated to

"YWJjZKM="

 which is not

STRING=

 to

"YWJjZMKj"


 --------------------------------
```

Comment: I can decode `YWJjZKM=` on the website with *iso-8859-1* charset, I don't know exactly where it does come from

Comment: @coredump It works because iso-8859-1 is an 8-bit extension of ASCII and includes all ASCII characters as the first 128 characters, followed by an additional 128 characters to cover a broader range of characters.

Comment: I just tried inserting a UTF-8 BOM at the beginning of my source file.  It made no difference.

Answer (score 4):

You are almost certainly not handling UTF-8 properly, or at all.  In particular assuming `stdutils` is [this](https://github.com/eslick/cl-stdutils) then its `string-to-usb8-array` is

```
(defun-exported string-to-usb8-array (str)
  (declare (simple-string str))
  (let* ((len (length str))
     (vec (make-usb8-array len)))
    (declare (fixnum len)
         (type (simple-array (unsigned-byte 8) (*)) vec)
         (optimize (speed 3)))
    (do ((i 0 (1+ i)))
    ((= i len) vec)
      (declare (fixnum i))
      (setf (aref vec i) (char-code (schar str i))))))
```

which is not even trying to deal with UTF-8.  It coincidentally 'works' because the character code for `#\£` is less than 256.

I have not checked the other case but I am sure it is the same.

If you need to base64 encode the UTF-8 representation of a string you need to make sure you do turn it into its UTF-8 encoding, or that the base64 encoder does that for you.  In particular there is no such thing as a 'UTF-8 string' in CL: CL strings are vectors of characters, *not* vectors of octets which are some encoding of those characters. (Apologies if you know this already.)

If you want to use `cl-base64` then an answer is probably to use [Trivial UTF-8](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/UNOFFICIAL/docs/trivial-utf-8/doc/index.html):

```
> (cl-base64:usb8-array-to-base64-string
   (trivial-utf-8:string-to-utf-8-bytes "abcd£"))
"YWJjZMKj"

> (cl-base64:usb8-array-to-base64-string
   (trivial-utf-8:string-to-utf-8-bytes "abcdπ"))
"YWJjZM+A"
```

The second case includes a character (`#\π`) whose code is not below 256.

---

However I would be tempted to look for a base64 encoding tool which was aware that strings must be encoded: it looks like both `cl-base64` and `stdutils` are rather old code (`stdutils` has conformance problems apart from anything else).  Unfortunately I don't know of such a thing.